# looping after if statement and continue the for loop

Tags: python, loops, text, data-extraction

I'm trying to loop over a .txt file, when I find a keyword, I want to loop over the next 5 rows, but I can't make my loop continue.

This is the text:

```
11/9/2022 12:37 a. m. - J E. Meta: *Plantilla de contacto*
Respuesta #10002
Nombre: Jesus Meta 
Numero Telefonico: 656-199-4322
Monto de Credito: 1200
Numero de Cliente: 127388
Ya tiene su ultimo estacional pagado?: Si
```

When I find the keyword "Respuesta" I want the loop to continue over the next 5 rows: so I need to get:

```
Nombre:
Numero:
Monto:
Etc:
```

This is my code, I'm able to find the keyword! but after finding the keyword, my loop stops and I can't make it continue so that I get the next 5 rows I need to get.

```
import os 


path = os.getcwd() + "/prestamos.txt"

with open(path) as file:
    data = file.readlines()
    for row in data:
        if "Respuesta" in row:
            print(row)
```

Thanks!

**Code that worked for me**

I ended up sticking to a different loop with while:

This is the code that worked for me in case it helps someone else:

```
import os 
import pandas as pd

path = os.getcwd() + "/prestamos.txt"

ls = {}
with open(path) as file:
    data = file.readlines()
    n = 0
    while n <= len(data)-1:
        if "Respuesta" in data[n]:
            r = range(n,n+6)
            for row in r:
                #print(row,data[row])
                col,actual_data = data[row].strip().split(":")
                #print(col,actual_data)
                if col not in ls:
                    ls.update({col:[actual_data]})
                elif col in ls:
                    ls[col].append(actual_data)

        n += 1



df = pd.DataFrame(ls)
print(df.head())
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the way that you did it:

```
import os 


path = os.getcwd() + "/prestamos.txt"

with open(path) as file:
    data = iter(file.readlines())
    for row in data:
        if "Respuesta" in row:
            print(row)
            # printing the next 5 lines as well:
            for _ in range(5):
                print(next(data))
```

Or with some modification and a bit more flexibility:

```
import os 

path = os.getcwd() + "/prestamos.txt"

with open(path) as file:
    # since `file` is a text file, you can loop directly over it
    for line in file:
        if 'Respuesta' in line:
            next_5 = [next(file) for _ in range(5)]
            # now, next_5 is a list of those 5 lines, you can work with it
        # the code would continue and find the next block, if you file has multiple
```

Comment: both versions fail for me because next() can not be applied here.

Comment: The first was missing an `iter()`, the second was missing the parameters to `range`, i.e. `(5)` - both solutions now work on a file with the content you shared.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution:

```
import os 


path = os.getcwd() + "/prestamos.txt"

with open(path) as file:
    count = 0
    found = false
    for row in data:
        if 'Respuesta' in data:
            found = true
            count = 0
        if found and count < 5:
            print(row)
            count += 1
```

Here I use `found` to keep track of when I find `"Respuesta"`. Then I use `count` to keep track of the number of lines after I find it.